# ReactJs -- on the click event on li element the class is not immediately added

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, onclick

I am trying to add some simple class with some styling on clicked li element.The very first li element works perfectly but the other li element takes double click to apply the class (styling).
Please tell me why this behaviour is happening.

## App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state={
    clicked: false,
    index: 0,
    arr: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
  }

  handleClick = (i) => {

    this.setState({
      clicked: !this.state.clicked,
      index: i
    });

  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.index);
    return (
      <div className='App'>
         <ul>
           {
             this.state.arr.map((el, i) => (
             <li key={i} className={(this.state.clicked && this.state.index === i) ? 'clicked':''} 
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}>{el}</li>
             ))
           }
         </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

## App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60vw;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}

li{
  padding: 4px 7px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clicked{
  background: #000;
  color: white;
}
```

The clicked class in css is what i am applyying programmatically.
What I am missing here ?

Comment: Use the `setState(state => ({ clicked: !state.clicked, ... })` instead of relying on the imperative value on the component.

Comment: but its not fixing the issue.Still on double click only the class is added except the first li element which is added on single click.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Just realized that we are reassigning the `clicked` on each click. It must be always true after the first click.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state={
    clicked: false,
    index: 0,
    arr: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
  }

  handleClick = (i) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      clicked: true,
      index: i
    }));
  }
  
  render() {
    const shouldAddClassName = this.state.clicked === true;
    const currentIndex = this.state.index;
    console.log('currentIndex', currentIndex);
    return (
      <div className='App'>
         <ul>
           {
             this.state.arr.map((el, i) => (
             <li key={i} className={(shouldAddClassName && currentIndex === i) ? 'clicked': ''} 
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}>{el}</li>
             ))
           }
         </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60vw;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 4px 7px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clicked {
  background: #000;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the handleClick() function put below code::

handleClick = (i) => {
    this.setState({
      clicked: true,
      index: i
    });
  }
clicked: true for instantly applying class on every li element. And it will fix your double click thing too.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your handleClick function with this one and you are good to go:

```
  handleClick = (i) => {
    this.setState({ clicked: false }, () => {
      this.setState({
        clicked: true,
        index: i
      });
    })
  }
```

The reason is your code is not working because when your clicked is already active then double click is used to add the clicked class. First click is use to remove the clicked from your already clicked element and the other one to active the new clicked class.

I hope it will be helpful to you.